# 3 Circles inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

Two small identical circles of radii
5 cm and a big circle of radius 8 cm
are embedded in rectangle ABCD. The
circles are tangential to the
rectangle. Given that AB = 34cm, find
the area of rectangle ABCD in $cm^2$.

My attempt:
Let the gap between the tangents (parallel to each other and perpendicular to ab) for the bigger and smaller circle be x. By symmetry
$$
34 = 10 + 10 + 16 - 2x\\\therefore x=1
$$
I couldn't seem to go further than this. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sorry for a slightly different labeling of the points.*

Triangle POX is rectangle with sides $$OX=8+5=13,\; XP=CD/2=12,\; OP=\sqrt{13^2-12^2}=5.$$
Therefore, the short side of the rectangle is $$MO+OP+XC=8+5+5=18.$$

[image]